# Javascript Validation with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to do jquery validation.

In the first one, I want one alphabet, then 8 numeric characters, then a dash(-) and then an alphabet. Ex:`C12345678-C`

In the second one same as the first one but, doesn't start with an alphabet: Eg: `12345678-C`

I have tried `var dni = /^(([0-9]{8}+)-\w+([a-z]{1}\w+)*)$/;`

How to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide code that you have tried.

Comment: var dni =  /^(([0-9]{8}+)-\w+([a-z]{1}\w+)*)$/;

Comment: this is for  12345678-C this format

Comment: actually this working but i want to give limits to numric means no one enter more then 8 numrics

Comment: So please edit your question and insert your code there.

Comment: Try with code - 

`"C12345678-C".match("^[A-Z]{1}[1-9]{8}[-]{1}[A-Z]{1}$")`
`"12345678-C".match("^[1-9]{8}[-]{1}[A-Z]{1}$")`

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern

```
var pattern = /^([A-Z]{1}[\d]{8}-[A-Z]{1}|[\d]{8}-[A-Z]{1})$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below Regex to check and add your logic

You can also check/test in this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/shoesheill/smqtywgh/1/)

http://jsfiddle.net/shoesheill/smqtywgh/1/

```
var sentence="SushilC12345678-CShrestha";
var firstRegex=/[a-zA-z]{1}[0-9]{8}-[a-zA-z]{1}/gm;
var pattern1=sentence.match(firstRegex);
var secondRegex=/[0-9]{8}-[a-zA-z]{1}/gm;
var pattern2=sentence.match(secondRegex);
alert("First Pattern is: "+pattern1);
alert("Second Pattern is: "+pattern2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following regex should do the job:

C12345678-C --> `/([A-Z]{1}\d{8}\-+[A-Z]{1})/g`

12345678-C --> `/(\d{8}\-+[A-Z]{1})/g`

If you want and need you can switch to lower case characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try with code -

```
"C12345678-C".match("^[A-Z]{1}[1-9]{8}[-]{1}[A-Z]{1}$") 
"12345678-C".match("^[1-9]{8}[-]{1}[A-Z]{1}$")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
/^[A-Za-z]?\d{8}\-[A-Za-z]$/;
```

```js
var patt = /^[A-Za-z]?\d{8}\-[A-Za-z]$/;

console.log( patt.test('12345678-C') );
console.log( patt.test('a12345678-C') );
console.log( patt.test('*12345678-C') );
console.log( patt.test('*12345678C') );
```